# How to send EOF on Prolog swipl REPL on Windows to close the pseudo user file?

Tags: prolog, eof, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm using the `swipl.exe` Prolog REPL on Windows and trying to use the [user pseudo file](https://www.swi-prolog.org/man/quickstart.html#sec:consultuser) opened with `[user].` but I can't figure out the key shortcut to leave the pseudo file:

```
c:\code>swipl.exe
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.3)

1 ?- [user].
|: hello :- format('Hello world~n').
|: ^Z

.

ERROR: user://1:9:3: Syntax error: illegal_character
|:
Action (h for help) ? ^C
c:\code>
```

Starting at the `^Z` I typed the keys

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (I expected here should have sent the EOF)
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- <kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (this shows an error, and puts me back into the pseudo file)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (this kills only one of the two swipl processes, leaving the console in a broken state with some keystrokes going to swipl and some going to cmd(!))

---

I know that on a blank line pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> normally works to send EOF, like if in `more.com` I type <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> everything works on my terminal.

---

If I run the `swipl-win.exe` GUI following the same key steps, immediately when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it closes the pseudo file and returns me to the top-level query:

```
?- [user].
|: hello :- format('Hello world~n').
|: 
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- hello.
Hello world
true.

?-
```

---

What do I press to get `[user].` to work in `swipl.exe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, when you type `[user]`, you're consulting a pseudo source file, which is made of **terms**. Therefore, simply type the term `end_of_file`. For example:

```
?- [user].
|: a.
|: b.
|: end_of_file.

% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
true.
```